# Possible match for (seemingly) invalid Lua-pattern

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, lua-5.2

I know that you can't repeat match groups in Lua. For example, if I wanted to match the two successive `"45"`'s, I can't do:

```
print(string.find("some 4545 text", "(%d%d)+"))
```

which will print `nil` (no match found).

However, since `find(...)` doesn't report an error (for the invalid patterns `"%"` and `"(%d"` errors *are* produced), it leads me to believe the pattern `"(%d%d)+"` *is* a valid one.

If `"(%d%d)+"` is a valid pattern, what does it match? And if it isn't, is there a particular reason no error is produced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"(%d%d)+" *is* a valid pattern. It matches for example "some 45+67 text" or "some 4567+ text" and captures "45" in the first case and "67" in the second.

Comment: Aha, the `+` simply becomes a literal instead of a meta character (that's very different from the regex/pattern-match engines I'm used to). Thanks!

Comment: The other regexes i know have this ambiguity: Parenthesis are used for grouping (there the + makes sense) and for captures. In lua patterns, there is no grouping, thus... But yeah, the manual could state that a bit more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

To match two successive occurrences of a string of digits, use `"(%d+)%1"`.

Comment: Thanks, although I knew that already. My question was what the pattern `"(%d%d)+"` is supposed to match (in case it is valid).